# How to make a previous DIV text bold using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kmgj8ny9/

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".chosen-select").chosen();

    $("body").on("focus", ".htLeft", function (e) {
        //alert(this);
        $(this).parent("div").parent("div").find("div:first-child").first().removeClass("setNormal").addClass("setBold");
    });
    $("body").on("focusout", ".htLeft", function (e) {
        $(this).parent("div").parent("div").find("div:first-child").first().removeClass("setBold").addClass("setNormal");
    });
});
```

If the textarea is focused, the `Comments` label is bold, but if the dropdownlist is focused, the `Issue` label isn't bold.

The dropdownlist is a HTML generated ASP.net control.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: replace `focusout` by `blur`. Remember that *focusout*: is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

Comment: @kmsdev The fiddle has the HTML/JQuery/CSS code. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the parent of a clicked "select" is a div? Why not set ids like "issue_label" and "issue_input" and make the connection with those?

Comment: You're using the chosen javascript library which is changing the structure of your HTML. Your selector will not find the label.

Comment: The `chosen()`-plugin will replace the select with a div. So this div does not have the class `.htleft` anymore

Comment: @Ben, because this is just an example. I have many DIVs

Comment: @empiric You may be right... :/ bummer. Do I need multiple jquery code than?

Comment: Answer updated with various improvements. I would personally go with the third (shortest) one, unless you actually need two classes to style the labels. Cheers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update

Based on the new HTML provided, I have tweaked the selectors to target the input elements created by the chosen plugin as well as your inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();

    $("body").on("focusin", ".htLeft, .chosen-search input", function (e) {
        console.log(this);
        $(this).closest(".section").find(".span_small:first").removeClass("setNormal").addClass("setBold");
    });
    $("body").on("focusout", ".htLeft, .chosen-search input", function (e) {
        $(this).closest(".section").find(".span_small:first").removeClass("setBold").addClass("setNormal");
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kmgj8ny9/12/

You can also combine the event handlers into one and check the `event.type` property to decide if you are `focusin` or `focusout` and toggle the classes accordingly:

```
$("body").on("focusin focusout", ".htLeft, .chosen-search input", function (e) {
    var focusin = e.type == "focusin";
    $(this).closest(".section").find(".span_small:first").toggleClass("setNormal", !focusin).toggleClass("setBold", focusin);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kmgj8ny9/13/

Typically you would only need one class, which you toggle, rather than two as the default styling should be the same as `setNormal`. That means you can shorten it further to this:

e.g.

```
$("body").on("focusin focusout", ".htLeft, .chosen-search input", function (e) {
    $(this).closest(".section").find(".span_small:first").toggleClass("setBold", e.type == "focusin");
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kmgj8ny9/14/

---

### Original answer

Because of the plugin you are using for the dropdown, the control that gets focus in the dropdown is not `.htLeft`. That element has been buried within other elements to make the "pretty" control you see.

Try this as a quick fix:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".chosen-select").chosen();

    $("body").on("focusin", ".htLeft,:has(.htLeft)", function (e) {
        //alert(this);
        $(this).closest(".section").find("div:first-child").first().removeClass("setNormal").addClass("setBold");
    });
    $("body").on("focusout", ".htLeft,:has(.htLeft)", function (e) {
        $(this).closest(".section").find("div:first-child").first().removeClass("setBold").addClass("setNormal");
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kmgj8ny9/3/

Normally I view the DOM in my browser to see what elements get created by plugins and target something specific to them.

Note: `closest` is always preferable to something like `parent("div").parent("div")` as it handles DOM changes.

Comment: Note: My solution above actually fires multiple focus events for a single focus change (it is just not visible). You really need to target the plugin element that gets focus instead. Thanks :)

Comment: Also note: I am not happy with the `find("div:first-child").first().` selectors, but the alternatives I have tried so far don't work properly, so sticking with your selectors for now :)

Comment: It makes other label bold when hovered over because I have many `.section`

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: Please provide a better example of your HTML and I will tweak it to suit your situation :)

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: Mocked up enough HTML to test it. Answer updated to use better selectors for both event matching and label matching. Hope this meets your requirements now.

Comment: the second one with the combined worked just great. Thank you very much for your help.; +1 and ACCEPT!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use mouseover and mouseout :http://jsfiddle.net/kmgj8ny9/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".chosen-select").chosen();


   $("body").on("mouseover", ".htLeft", function (e) {              
      $(this).parent("div").find("div:first-child").first().removeClass("setNormal").addClass("setBold");
   });

    $("body").on("mouseout", ".htLeft", function (e) {
        $(this).parent("div").find("div:first-child").first().removeClass("setBold").addClass("setNormal");
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

After I gave it a little more thought, I believe `.mouseup()` would work better for this task.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie soo weird it only works in the original window I created it! A bug in jsfiddle???!!!

Comment: `mouseover/out` is a really bad option anyway as it negates keyboard navigation.

Comment: @erkaner, the browser blocks mixed content when you try to load non secure content (the libraries in this case) into secure content (your fiddle)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5b8LfLuf/   If you add the references using the format "//harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" in jsfiddle or in a regular html file, the browser will automatically determine http or https.